# MYSQL vertical sort using different columns?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I'm not sure if this is possible--I've been trying to get this to work with a CASE statement, but am having no luck.

I have about 7 columns each assigned with a false/true value for a different state such as:

```
MA  VT  CT  DE
0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0
```

What I'd like to do is sort rows ascending based on STATE. Every time I try more than one column in my CASE statement, I get an error in PHPmyAdmin. In the example below, I'm just trying to sort two states to get the syntax right. Not sure if it's me, or if this isn't possible:

```
SELECT 
   *  
FROM 
   tblState D
ORDER BY 
    case when MA then 1 else 0 end
    case when VT then 2 else 0 end
ASC
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What should happen if both `MA` and `VT` are true for a row?

Comment: What's the expected output for the above data? Are you trying to get row IDs?

Comment: That is a very good question! I don't know if it happens, but I will have to check out the db. If states are not mutually exclusive, am I in trouble?

Comment: The expected output will be something like ID, State, Description, Topic. But the primary sort is the state, not the ID.

Comment: @user2855835 don't go away just by saying thanks if really want to thanks someone on SO then read [*how to say thanks on SO*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: Thanks for the link... I accepted the answer. Tried the vote-up all around, but looks like I don't have the 15 rep yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do this, assuming you want the states in alphabetical order:

```
order by CT desc, DE desc, MA desc, VT desc
```

Comment: Thanks so much Gordon, et al. This is just what I need and I was banging my head against the wall! Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using multiple case statements and as per your question it can be done within one case statement

```
SELECT 
   *  
FROM 
   tblState D
ORDER BY 
    case when MA then 1 
         when VT then 2 
         else 0
        end
ASC
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95e9b/2)

Comment: Thank you, M. This works, too. Incidentally, I've used jsfiddle before, but had no idea there was a sql fiddle. So thanks for that, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you following your approach ([SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bff54/1)):

```
SELECT 
*  
FROM 
tblState

ORDER BY

CASE MA WHEN 1 THEN MA END DESC,
CASE VT WHEN 1 THEN VT END DESC,
CASE CT WHEN 1 THEN CT END DESC,
CASE DE WHEN 1 THEN DE END DESC
```

The simpler way is like Gordon Linoff told you:

```
order by CT desc, DE desc, MA desc, VT desc
```